# How can I get this paper?

Tags: reference-request

"Formule de Weyl et de Demazure et Theoreme dc Borel-Weil-Bott pour les algebres de Kac-Moody generates"

by O.Mathieu.

I even do not know whether he published on a Mathematical Journal or not.

Can anyone tell me how to find this article?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct reference is O. Mathieu, Formules de Demazure-Weyl, et généralisation du théorème de Borel-Weil-Bott, *C.R. Acad. Sci. Paris* **303** (1986), 391-394 [MR 87m:17036](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=862200).

Comment: Interesting discrepancy between the titles on Mathscinet and Zentralblatt, but at least the journal references is the same.

Comment: Um, let me add that that is just an announcement of his result. I think the proof actually appears in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=980506

Comment: @unknown, it was my mistake. The title of [Mat1] is incorrect in 
http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2001-38-01/S0273-0979-00-00891-0/ which is what Goggle found... Apparently this was the title of a preprint.

Answer (score 5):

Did you consider looking it up on Mathscinet/Google Scholar/Zentralblatt and then order it through your library?

au:Mathieu, Olivier & ti:demazure & py:1986-1986 on zentralblatt gives

Mathieu, Olivier

Formules de Demazure-Weyl, et généralisation du théorème de Borel-Weil-Bott. (Demazure-Weyl formulas, and generalization of the Borel-Weil-Bott theorem). (French)

[J] C. R. Acad. Sci., Paris, Sér. I 303, 391-394 (1986). ISSN 0764-4442

but I also got this information with a google search.

Edited to add: Look at Willie Wong's comment to the accepted answer. The above reference corresponds to the question, but the actual long article is presumably

MR980506 (90d:17024) 17B67 (14M15 17B10 20G05)
Mathieu, Olivier Formules de caractères pour les algèbres de Kac-Moody générales. (French) [Character formulas for general Kac-Moody algebras] Astérisque No. 159-160 (1988), 267 pp.

Comment: Might I add the remark that you can use Zentralblatt for a search like this even if your institution is not subscribed in contrast to mathscinet?

Comment: And a search author: Mathieu, title: Demazure on the free MR Lookup yields the same result.